# Sequential email send in Thunderbird like one can do in Outlook?

Tags: email, thunderbird, smtp

I tried to queue up a bunch of emails with large file attachments in Thunderbird 9 and it immediately tried to send each one when I clicked send. The large amount of simultaneous emails choked my SMTP server connection and they failed.

Is there a way to configure Thunderbird to actually make use of the outbox and send emails one by one the way my Outlook 2010 does?

Comment: What about "Send Later" and then "Send Unsent Messages"?